# passing an ArrayList to a function makes changes in the original ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to pass the same ArrayList from the main function to 3 different functions (all in different classes).

When the 1st function receives the ArrayList, it makes changes not only in the local copy of the list but also the original ArrayList in the main method gets modified. This indicates that the changes are being made at the memory address.

So, in the first function I copied the received arraylist into another arraylist of the same type, using:

```
for(int i=0;i<valuex.size();i++)
{
  temp1=valuex.get(i);        
  VALUE.add(temp1);
}
```

This worked for the first time when I introduced this modification but then the same problem restored. Later I made three copies of the arraylist and passed each copy to each of the 3 functions. This too failed.

I didn't use

```
clone();
```

because this created the same problem some time back..
Please help...

Comment: What are you changing in the method ? adding/removing elements or modifying the objects in the list?

Comment: It's a Class type List and I'm modifying the objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have described a shallow copy - you've made a fresh list, but you've got the same objects in each list.

If this isn't working for you, it suggests your method is modifying the list objects. To avoid this being a problem, you'll have to perform a deep copy - creating copies of each of your objects.

For example:

```
List<Foo> oldList = // ...
List<Foo> newList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Foo foo : oldList) {
  Foo newFoo = new Foo(foo); // copy constructor
  newList.add(newFoo);
}
```

Comment: okay...u mean to say I extract every object at each location from the original list and then add it to the new list?

Comment: @DonCorleone More specifically, you must make a copy of each object before you add it to the other list.

Comment: ok...thanks...can you please show me an example (give a link to an example)..it will be very helpful

Comment: @DonCorleone I gave you an example in my answer. Google "copy constructor" if you don't understand what one is.

Answer (score 1):

When you passed a copy of the list to your three methods, you passed a reference to a copy of the list **as a data structure**. However, both lists, in memory, ended up pointing to the very same objects.

If your methods are changing the actual objects that the lists are pointing to, and you'd like to avoid that, then cloning the list is not enough: you must clone each and every object in the list as well.

By the way: the reason that `clone()` didn't work for you is that `clone()` only performs a *shallow clone* of the list: it creates a brand new `ArrayList` instance in memory, however the list's constituents are still the same objects (in memory) as the objects pointed-to by the original list.

Comment: ok..so I if every location of the list contains 4 objects, should i clone each of them separately in the new list?

Answer (score -3):

You can just create a new ArrayList based on your existing arrayList before passing it in as argument.

```
List existingList = new ArrayList();
o1.m1(new ArrayList(existingList));
o2.m2(new ArrayList(existingList));
o3.m3(new ArrayList(existingList));
```

ArrayList contructor allows you to create a new ArrayList based on an existing collection.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(java.util.Collection)

Comment: The OP is already doing that (creating a shallow copy of the list).